# JavaScript error cannot get input from <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am  learner to Java Script and was trying to run this code where user enter any value in input text and then the inputted data gets print in ***"p"*** tag but when i used debugger to see where the code went wrong it pops me out with the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

*Code:*

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
    <script>
     function myFunction() 
     {
       var a = document.getElementById("txt_1")[0].value;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
     }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="txt_1" name="txt_1">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click me">
    </form>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)** will return a single element. So you don't need to indexing `[0]`. Remove the `[0]` from the `getElementById("txt_1")[0]`.

```html
 <html>
     <head>
    <script>
     function myFunction() 
     {
       var a = document.getElementById("txt_1").value;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
     }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="txt_1" name="txt_1">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click me">
    </form>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks for help can you tell me then at what specific do we use  "indexing" i.e. ** [0].value**  in JavaScript ?

Comment: @MehulChachada indexing you can use with `arrays` and `array like` objects.So if you have many `p` elements and want to get all elements by 
`getElementsByTagName` function, it will return an `array like` object.For each element in that `array like` object your can call `[]` and pass the index of the item in the object

Answer (score 0):

The function `document.getElementById("txt_1")` returns the element, not an array that has the element as the first item, so remove the `[0]`:

```
var a = document.getElementById("txt_1").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById() returns a single element. No need to (you can't) select the first element (`[0]`), there will be only one.

```
var a = document.getElementById("txt_1").value;
```